# Combine must and should

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I've some troubles with an elasticsearch query. (I use elasticsearch 5). I want to combine must bool query and should in order to create a query which match this condition :

```
Get users which match (city = x) AND (school = y) AND (age = 12) AND (team = a OR b)
```

I tried many queries but I still have a query malformed exception.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must" : [
        {
          "match": {
            "city": "x"
          }
        },
        {
          "match" : {
            "school" : "y"
        }
        },
        {
          "match" : {
            "age" : 12
        },
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {"term": {"team": "A"}},
              {"term": {"team": "B"}}
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I hope someone could help me :D

Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok. And why the query you have doesn't work?

Comment: And when you copy-pasted your query, you probably wanted to leave something out but you forgot to add a curly brace for the `bool` statement. Or this is your error in the query.

Comment: I got this error :
  {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 19,
        "col": 11
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
    "line": 19,
    "col": 11
  },
  "status": 400
}

Comment: If I put my bool / should inside curly braces It returns a "Bad String" error (I use Kibana to test my queries)

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "city": "x"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "school": "y"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "age": 12
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "team": "A"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "team": "B"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hell yeah ! I just find the solution before you send it ! Thx a lot :) You saved my day :p

Comment: Thanks for the follow up and confirming.